# Algebraic models of cohomology classes of (higher) Eilenberg-Maclane Spaces?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, group-cohomology

In [Classification of weak 3-groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271877/classification-of-weak-3-groups), Qiaochu gave an excellent answer, in which, he mentioned cohomology classes $H^{4}(B^{2}\pi_{2};\pi_{3})$ can be viewed as quadratic refinement of Whitehead bracket (where $\pi_{2},\,\pi_{3}$ are (discrete) abelian groups and $B$ is delooping.) In this case, Whitehead bracket is a binary operation $\pi_{2}\times\pi_{2}\to\pi_{3}$.

He didn't point out any ref for this point there and I can't find any. So my first question is:

Q1: How to see above algebraic meaning of $H^{4}(B^{2}\pi_{2};\pi_{3})$?

I have found some ref on nLab [Whitehead product](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Whitehead+product), but it didn't say anything on the cohomology class (at least in an obvious way to me).

Besides, I want to ask a more general question. We know that algebraically, $H^{*}(K(G,1))$ can be modelled by group cocycles (with a suitable target). So my second question is

Q2: Is there an algebraic model for $H^{*}(K(G;n))$ for general non-negative integer $n$?

Comment: You should have a look at the series of papers “on the groups H(\pi,n)” by Eilenberg and MacLane. For the very first question you can also have a look at the Joyal-Street paper on braided tensor categories.

Comment: Thank you for the references @FernandoMuro! I will have a look.